# Sharing property variables across classes

Tags: objective-c

I have a class that I want to store a string into. This class is aController. Now I want to store a string from bController and NSLog the string in cController. When I try this the output of the log in the cController is always null. Any help would be much appreciated.

aController.h:

```
@interface aController : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * testingProperty;
```

aController.m:

```
#import "aController.h"

@implementation aController

@synthesize testingProperty = _testingProperty;
```

bController.m:

```
#import "bController.h"
#import "aController.h"

@implementation bController

-(void)didSomething
{
    aController* aTest = [[aController alloc] init];
    aTest.testingProperty = @"Test String";
}
```

cController.m

```
#import "cController.h"
#import "aController.h"

@implementation cController

-(void)didSomethingElse
{
    aController* bTest = [[aController alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"%@",bTest.testingProperty); //output is: (null)
}
```

Comment: Means that `bController didSomething` is never called. Put a log statement there to verify that it is invoked

Answer (score 1):

this is because your property is backed by a instance variable so if you allocate a new instance its nil. If you need to do this you have a couple of options. 1, you could create a singelton. 2, you could declare a class (+) method or two that can set and return your string that would be backed by a static variable. There probably exists some more ways to do this but maybe the easiest one would be the second one listed here.

Edit:

For your specific issue the app delegate will always be the same instance just put a property in your app delegate.h file and assign to it the string you get when you run the method. Then you can get that string like this:

```
YourAppDelegateClass *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegateClass *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSString *string = appDelegate.yourProperty;
```

Comment: Why wouldn't I have to do this? Let's say I run "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:" in my AppDelegate class and the output of that method is the device token. If I want to use that device token string in lets say a view controller or any other class... What is the best practice solution for achieving this?